# "Enable_if" a struct data menber

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++17, code-duplication

Isn't there any "cleaner" way (I mean less duplicate code) to write the following?

```
template < bool condition >
class Test {

  struct Foo1 {

    int a;
  };

  struct Foo2 {

    int a;
    int b;
  };

  using type = std::conditional_t<condition, Foo1, Foo2>;
};
```

All I want to do here, is to enable or disable a single data member of the struct. So it would be nice if I needed only one struct.

Something like:

```
template < bool condition >
class Test {

  struct type {
    int a;
    if constexpr(condition)
      int b;
  };
};
```

Comment: How about inheritance? Make `Foo2` inherit from `Foo1`? That would "mean less duplicate code" at least. That's also the "natural" way to extend structures and classes in object-oriented languages.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes that would be less code but that's not really what I was hoping. I guess I need to add more context.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel: That's not really "more context", as you haven't explained *why* you want that. And how you plan to use it.

Comment: @NicolBolas The problem is that if I give more context, everyone is gonna say that I don't need to do this. I have already a solution far more flexible (even if it would be really nice to get something better), but I was just curious if it was possible to get something like the second code snippet in C++ at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is "cleaner" for you, but... you can write an auto-inheriting (a sort of) class `Foo` in this way (unfortunately, it's can be done but outside `Test`)

```
// common part
template <bool>
struct Foo
 { int a; };

// only when `Cond` is true
template <>
struct Foo<true> : public Foo<false>
 { int b; };
```

and `Test` become

```
template <bool Cond>
struct Test
 { using type = Foo<Cond>; };
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
template <bool>
struct Foo
 { int a; };

template <>
struct Foo<true> : public Foo<false>
 { int b; };

template <bool Cond>
struct Test
 { using type = Foo<Cond>; };

int main ()
 {
   decltype(Test<true>::type::a)   a1;
   decltype(Test<true>::type::b)   b1;
   decltype(Test<false>::type::a)  a0;
   // decltype(Test<false>::type::b)  b0;  // compilation error
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it's still really far from the pseudo-code I wrote. It's probably not possible anyway, but I'll wait a little just in case.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel - unfortunately I know how to simply enable/disable methods, not data members.